# removing question mark from the end of URLs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm new to laravel and I'm working on building a crud application. Here is my web.php file with all the routes.
[image: web.php file]

For the creae, show, and edit GET routes, when I go to those routes on the browser, I see a "?" at the end of URLs, such as "localhost:3000/positiontypes.create?". I've been trying to figure out how to remove it from there but no success so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `?` denotes the beginning of a Query String, like `?foo=bar&bar=baz`, etc. Directly navigating to a Route shouldn't do that, but it also doesn't do anything if it is present and empty, so you're trying to solve a non-issue.

Comment: May I know how are you redirecting on those routes from your code?

Comment: @TimLewis  Yes, I understand why it's there but even for a get request if there are no query params then I don't understand why it gets added? And what's interesting is for the first 2 get requests in the web.php file there is no question mark appended to the URL.

Comment: What _exactly_ does "going to these routes" mean - did you type the URL into the browser address bar manually, did you follow links (if so, what did those have their href set to), did you submit forms ...?

Comment: @Bhushan Yes, for example for the show route, this is how I'm redirecting to it: <form action="{{ route('positiontypes.show', ['id' => $positiontype->id]) }}" method="GET">

Comment: @CBroe I have an index page which has a button that says "Create a new position type" and it's wrapped in a form tag just like in the comment above.

Comment: That's what I was saying: *"**Directly navigating** to a Route shouldn't do that [...]"* - `<a href="...">` is directly navigating, `<form method="GET" action="...">` is not direct navigation 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form will do a submit action and it will pass form attributes so it's setting a ? mark and as no attributes in that form so only ? mark is present in URL. Use anchor tag instead of a form. It will solve your issue.

```
<a href="{{ route('positiontypes.show', ['id' => $positiontype->id]) }}">Show </a>
```

Comment: This worked! There is no longer a "?" appended to the URLs. Thank you to all for helping!